# Performance comparison of STL sort on vector of strings vs. vector of string pointers

Tags: c++, string, performance, vector, stl

I tried to compare the performance of STL sort on vector of strings and vector of pointers to strings.

I expected the pointers version to outperform, but the actual results for 5 million randomly generated strings are

vector of strings : 12.06 seconds
vector of pointers to strings : 16.75 seconds

What explains this behavior? I expected swapping pointers to strings should be faster than swapping string objects.

The 5 million strings were generated by converting random integers.
Compiled with (gcc 4.9.3): `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall`
CPU: Xeon X5650

```
// sort vector of strings
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      const int numElements=5000000;
      srand(time(NULL));
      vector<string> vec(numElements);

      for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            vec[i] = std::to_string(rand() % numElements);

      unsigned before = clock();

      sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

      cout<< "Time to sort: " << clock() - before << endl;

       for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
         cout << vec[i] << endl;

      return 0;
    }



// sort vector of pointers to strings
    bool comparePtrToString (string *s1, string *s2)
    {
      return (*s1 < *s2);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      const int numElements=5000000;
      srand(time(NULL));
      vector<string *> vec(numElements);

      for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            vec[i] = new string( to_string(rand() % numElements));

      unsigned before = clock();

      sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comparePtrToString);

      cout<< "Time to sort: " << clock() - before << endl;

       for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
         cout << *vec[i] << endl;

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: With the pointer version, the strings might not be stored in continuous memory? Maybe you are experiencing a slow down through cache swapping all the time?

Comment: @Ben, cache swapping may be an explanation. Are there any profiling tools to measure the relative amounts of cache swapping between the two versions?

Comment: In your "vector of strings" version, the strings are stored on the stack (usually fast memory) and accessed with register vars. In your "vector of pointers" version, the strings are stored on the heap (using "new", usually slow memory). String comparisons will be more expensive when the strings must be retrieved from slow memory.

Comment: Cache-locality is king.

Comment: @ThomasG I don't know of any tools to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the gcc options (e.g. `-O3 -march=native`), and the CPU type (e.g. Intel Sandybridge (i5-2500k), or AMD Piledriver (some AMD model number)).  The extra level of indirection to get at the data being compared should produce a similar slowdown on most CPUs, but it's still good practice to include that data in any microbenchmark question.  As you can see at http://agner.org/optimize/, different CPUs have different internals with different bottlenecks and different cache latencies.

Comment: If you need to sort strings, use a linked list. Then you are only moving pointers around not data.

Comment: As the answers point out, the swapping of string objects is at least as efficient as the swapping of pointers to strings. The reason is, the more recent versions of compilers implement it efficiently using move semantics and adjusting pointers, etc. I looked further into this by generating random strings of lengths varying from 10 to 1024 and sorting them.
The plain strings version always outperformed the pointers version, even for the strings whose length is more than 1000 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because all the operations that `sort` performs on `strings` is moves and swaps. Both move and swap for an `std::string` are constant time operations, meaning that they only involve changing some pointers.

Therefore, for both sorts moving of the data has the same performance overhead. However, in case of pointers to strings you pay some extra cost to dereference the pointers on each comparison, which causes it to be noticeably slower.

Comment: All of the other answers say _casting_ is the additional cost, when in reality, casting is a constant time operation.  _Dereferencing_ as you've mentioned, is the killer here.

Comment: Well, some castings (e.g. from `char*` to `std::string`) have price, but none of them are present in the OP's snippet.

Comment: Agreed, any type with a non-explicit single parameter constructor can induce a "hidden" cost -- hidden in terms that the conversion is implicit.  Minimizing dynamic allocations (to avoid memory fragmentation and all of the perils that come with it) is a desirable goal to strive for.

Comment: A `std::string` is typically bigger than a `std::string*` by a factor of 4 or thereabouts.  That factor is not nothing, even if it is dwarfed by other effects.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the internal **pointers** to representations of the strings are **swapped** and not the complete data copied.

You should not expect any benefit from the implementation with pointers, which in fact is slower, since the **pointers** have to be **dereferenced** additionally, to perform the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

> What explains this behavior? I expected swapping pointers to strings
>   should be faster than swapping string objects.

There's various things going on here which could impact performance.

1. **Swapping is relatively cheap both ways.** Swapping strings tends to always be a shallow operation (just swapping PODs like pointers and integrals) for large strings and possibly deep for small strings (but still quite cheap -- implementation-dependent). So swapping strings tends to be pretty cheap overall, and typically not much more expensive than simply swapping pointers to them*.

   *[`sizeof(string)` is certanly bigger than `sizeof(string*)`, but it's not an astronomical difference basically as the operation still
   occurs in constant-time, and quite a bit cheaper in this context
   when the string fields already have to be fetched into a faster form
   of memory for the comparator, giving us temporal locality with
   respect to its fields.]*
2. **String contents must be accessed anyway both ways.** Even the pointer version of your comparator has to examine the string contents (including the fields designating `size` and `capacity`). As a result, we end up paying the memory cost of fetching the data for the string contents regardless. Naturally if you just sorted the strings by pointer address (ex: without using a comparator) instead of a lexicographical comparison of the string contents, the performance edge should shift towards the pointer version since that would reduce the amount of data accessed considerably while improving spatial locality (more pointers can fit in a cache line than strings, e.g.).
3. **The pointer version is scattering (or at least increasing the stride of) the string fields in memory.** For the pointer version, you're allocating each string on the free store (in addition to the string contents which may or may not be allocated on the free store). That can disperse the memory and reduce locality of reference, so you're potentially incurring a greater cost in the comparator that way with increased cache misses. Even if a sequential allocation of this sort results in a very contiguous set of pages being allocated (ideal scenario), the stride to get from one string's fields to the next would tend to get at least a little larger because of the allocation metadata/alignment overhead (not all allocators require metadata to be stored directly in a chunk, but typically they will at least add some small overhead to the chunk size).

   It might be simpler to attribute this to the cost of dereferencing the pointer but it's not so much the cost of the `mov/load` instruction doing the memory addressing that's expensive (in this relative context) as loading from slower/bigger forms of memory that aren't already cached/paged to faster, smaller memory. Allocating each string individually on the free store will typically increase this cost whether it's due to a loss of contiguity or a larger constant stride between each string entry (in an ideal case).

   Even at a basic level without trying too hard to diagnose what's happening at the memory level, this increases the total size of the data that the machine has to look at (string contents/fields + pointer address) in addition to reduced locality/larger or variable strides (typically if you increase the amount of data accessed, it has to at least have improved locality to have a good chance of being beneficial). You might start to see more comparable times if you just sorted pointers to strings that were allocated contiguously (not in terms of the string contents which we have no control over, but just contiguous in terms of the adjacent string objects themselves -- effectively pointers to strings stored in an array). Then you'd get back the spatial locality at least for the string fields in addition to packing the data associated more tightly within a contiguous space.

Swapping smaller data types like indices or pointers can sometimes offer a benefit but they typically need to avoid examining the original contents of the data they refer to or provide a significantly cheaper swap/move behavior (in this case string is already cheap and becomes cheaper in this context considering temporal locality) or both.

Comment: Nice catch that each `string` is allocated separately in the pointers-to-strings version.  It's hard to design a micro-benchmark to measure exactly what you want to measure and avoid confounding factors.  Usually it requires enough knowledge to make a pretty solid guess at the result.  A more interesting benchmark would have been `std::string` vs. `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a `std::string` is typically about 3-4 times as big as a `std::string*`.
So just straight-up swapping two of the former shuffles that much more memory around.

But that is dwarfed by the following effects:

1. Locality of reference. You need to follow one more pointer to a random position to read the string.
2. More memory-usage: A pointer plus bookkeeping per allocation of each `std::string`.

Both put extra demand on caching, and the former cannot even be prefetched.

Answer (score 0):

Swaping containers change just container's content, in string case is the pointer to first character of string, not whole string.

In case vectors of pointers of strings you performed one additional step - casting pointers

Comment: Casting pointers? Unlikely, and that's often a 0-overhead operation anyway.